# Nivo Slider Strange behavior: Blank slide after the last image

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I was testing Nivo and I am getting this strange behavior that appears a blank slide after the last image, like a blank image, for a while and than starts again (normal). It's not random always after the last slide. 
I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery 1.7.1 and the code is:

```
                <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default"><div class="ribbon"></div>
                    <div id="nivoslider" class="nivoSlider" style="width:743px;height:295px;overflow: hidden">

                        <a href="#"><img src="images/nivo/banner740-optz.png" title="#teste1" alt="" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/nivo/nemo.jpg" title="#teste2" alt="" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/nivo/toystory.jpg" title="#teste3" alt="" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/nivo/walle.jpg" title="#teste4" alt="" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/nivo/up.jpg" title="#teste5" alt="" /></a>

                        <div id="teste1" class="nivo-html-caption">
                            <h4>Some Title</h4>
                            <p>Some paragraph</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="teste2" class="nivo-html-caption">
                            <h4>Some Title</h4>
                            <p>Some paragraph</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="teste3" class="nivo-html-caption">
                            <h4>Some Title</h4>
                            <p>Some paragraph</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="teste4" class="nivo-html-caption">
                            <h4>Some Title</h4>
                            <p>Some paragraph</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="teste5" class="nivo-html-caption">
                            <h4>Some Title</h4>
                            <p>Some paragraph</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps set up a jsFiddle so we can see this in action?

Comment: Oh! Thanks I forgot about that :). I'll set one up.

Comment: It seems that nivo won't work on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tenshimsm/bv4yX/7/

Comment: You'll need a <script> tag pointing to that I imagine. Also, get rid of all the "extra" stuff - jsFiddle doesn't need (or want) the <html> and <head> tags. Ideally the HTML would be *just* what you've got above, plus a script tag pulling in Nivo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tenshimsm/bv4yX/7/ is a working fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - looks to me like all the captions should be OUTSIDE the `#nivoSlider` div. I moved them down in my example at http://jsfiddle.net/bv4yX/10/ and it seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

My nivoslider also had bugs with bootstrap. My solution:
In *nivoslider.css*, `.nivoSlider img`:

```
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    /*bug fix bellow*/
    vertical-align: baseline !important;
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you José Neto. SpoonNZ's solution solved my problem already.
[Obrigado José Neto. A solução do SpoonNZ já resolveu meu problema.]